# Anchor <a> to Another Page Using Relative Paths - PHP

Tags: php, html, anchor, relative-url

I have an HTML page that has several anchors on it:

```
<h4>Anchor 1</h4><a name="anchor1"></a>
<p>blah blah</p>
<h4>Anchor 2</h4><a name="anchor2"></a>
<p>blah blah</p>
<h4>Anchor 3</h4><a name="anchor3"></a>
<p>blah blah</p>
```

Then, I have a PHP array to relative paths:

```
$anchor_array = array(
    'site/path/#anchor1' => 'Anchor 1',
    'site/path/#anchor2' => 'Anchor 2',
    'site/path/#anchor3' => 'Anchor 3',
);
```

Each `site/path/` has an `index.php` file inside so using `.htaccess` I'm able to use a link like this:

`site/path/`

This works fine, but when I add the anchor to it (eg,`site/path/#anchor1`) I get sent to the correct page, but not to the anchor location, just to the top of page.

What am I missing?

** EDIT **

After taking Salman A's advice, I was able to get 2/3 anchors to work properly.  But one was still causing me trouble.  I thought, perhaps, the browser is confusing the anchor name I have specified with something else.  So I did a test and changed the anchor from `anchor1` to `the_anchor1` (actually, I changed it from `history` to `our-history`) and it works now.

Is there a reason using `history` as anchor name is bad?

Comment: Do any of those anchor targets require the page to scroll? If the target page is short enough and/or none of the targets require scrolling, the browser can't move "down" to an anchor, because there isn't enough page height available to do that kind of move.

Comment: Good question...  The page is long enough that it should anchor to the correct location.  Scrolling is required, yes...

Comment: (i) Does the `#anchor1` appear in browser address bar? (ii) does the landing page contain `<a name=anchor1></a>`?

Comment: Yes. Here are the answers:  (i) result looks like this: `http://localhost/site/path/#anchor1/` and (ii) viewing source results in this: `<a name="anchor1"></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding:

> 1. result looks like this: `http://localhost/site/path/#anchor1/`
> 2. viewing source results in this:

You have a trailing slash in the hash portion of your URL. The browser will look for a named anchor with `name=anchor1/` (or `id=anchor1/`) which is not there obviously. Locate where the trailing slash is coming from and remove it.

Comment: I had originally tried your suggestion and it was giving spurious results.  For example, after changing it back, the anchors seem to work partly.  I moved them around a bit to see if I could tease them into working and one still isn't bring me to the correct spot.  You are basically correct, but I wish I coujld figure out the odd behavior.

Comment: Your solution was correct - thanks.  I had another issue confounding the results.  See edit above.